# PMD Eclipse run on file save

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I am using eclipse Juno and its PMD plugin. How can I set my eclipse to run PMD on file save action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the PMD in your project properties:

[image: Project properties (Eclipse)]

After that, PMD warnings and errors will be updated in Java files on saving.